# Android SDK missing on Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk

I just can't figure out how to install Android SDK to create new Android project on IntelliJ properly.

While trying to make a new project, red bold warning appears:
Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 24.0.2 or later.

The problem is, I don't really know how to fix it. Where could I eventually find accurate SDK and how to fix that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you never installed an Android SDK, you will first need to install it, as explained here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prerequisites-for-android-development.html

Then, go to File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings: SDKs.
Click on "+" and select Android SDK.
A dialog will open in which you should select the directory containing the Android SDK.
After you add it, you will be able to create an Android project in IntelliJ.

Answer (score -1):

Follow My below steps to fix your issue :

> **Click On SDK Manager**

[image: Click On SDK Manager]

> **Click on Launch Standalone SDK Manger**

[image: Click on Launch Standalone SDK Manger]

> **Update All the available support Libraries & tools**

[image: Update All the available support Libraries & tools]

Comment: But I have IntelliJ instead of Android Studio :/

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html

Comment: That link doesn't help for Android SDK packages

Comment: Intellij is interchangable with Android Studio, as long as you have the ultimate edition (I use intellij also for php)

Answer (score -1):

"Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure -> SDKs -> +" add here path to your Android SDK.